# Не работает {% extends %}

Tags: html, шаблонизаторы

Я создал 2 файла: test1.html и test2.html

Содержимое test1:

```
{% extends 'test2.html' %}
```

Содержимое test2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Если эта команда не должна работать, то чем её можно заменить, чтобы брать код из одного html, как из образца, и заменять лишь некоторые строчки...(наследовать)

Comment: В метках вопроса укажите используемый шаблонизатор

Comment: Выглядит как шаблон для Jinja.

Comment: И код, как вообще этот самый шаблонизатор используется, и пояснение, что такое "не работает"

Comment: Я делал без шаблонизатора

Comment: Ну тогда вполне логично, что extends ничего не делает

Comment: В html нет такого синтаксиса: `{% extends 'test2.html' %}`. Подобное включение файлов внутрь других делается через шаблонизаторы. Без шаблонизатора вы просто увидите этот текст в html.